# Surjective map between modules and generators

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

Suppose that $ \phi : N \to M$ is a surjective $R$-linear map. Show that if $N$ is finitely generated then so is $M$; and on the other hand if $M$ and ker $\phi$ are finitely generated then $N$ is finitely generated.

Here we are taking $M$ and $N$ to be $R$-modules. My initial thought about the first part of this problem is to consider the $(n_i)_{i \in I}$ (for a finite indexing set I) that generates $N$ and to use surjectivity to get the set $(m_i)$ that generate $M$ but I don't know if this is the right way to go or how to formalise this. For the second part, could the first isomorphism theorem be used and if so, how?

Comment: For the first one your idea will work. A hint for the second part, show that there exist $n_i$ (for finite indexing set I) such that for any $n \in N$, there exists a $n' \in \oplus Rn_i$ such that $\phi(n) = \phi(n')$.

Comment: thank you for the reply. I will try the first part. Please could you explain a bit more your notation for the second part? I thinkI recognise that symbol as the direct sum symbol but I'm not too sure what Rni is.

Comment: I mean that you should show there exist a finite set $n_1, \ldots, n_k$,  such that for any $n \in N$, you can find a $n' = a_1n_1 + \ldots + a_kn_k$ with $a_i \in R$ such that $\phi(n) = \phi(n')$.

Comment: Thank you, will think about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea is good. Suppose $\{n_1,\dots,n_k\}$ is a finite set of generators of $N$. If $y\in M$, there is $x\in N$ such that $y=\phi(x)$.

By assumption, $x=r_1n_1+\dots+r_kn_k$ and therefore
$$
y=\phi(x)=r_1\phi(n_1)+\dots+r_k\phi(n_k)
$$
which proves that $\{\phi(n_1),\dots,\phi(n_k)\}$ is a set of generators for $M$.

What about the other direction? Consider $\{n_1,\dots,n_k\}$ in $N$ such that $\{\phi(n_1),\dots,\phi(n_k)\}$ is a set of generators for $M$. This is possible because $M$ is, by assumption, finitely generated and $\phi$ is surjective. Take also a set of generators $\{v_1,\dots,v_l\}$ of $\ker\phi$.

Let $x\in N$. Then
$$
\phi(x)=r_1\phi(n_1)+\dots+r_k\phi(n_k)
$$
Consider $x'=r_1n_1+\dots+r_kn_k$. Observe that $x-x'\in\ker\phi$ and finish up.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! The first part makes perfect sense. However i'm not too sure on the second,specifically how x-x' is in the kernel?

Comment: ohh wait no I have got it haha.